# Missing Add Plugin button in WordPress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Missing Add Plugin button in WordPress Plugin.

What I did - turned off all plugins, cleaned cache, added define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS',true);

changed true to false - nothing worked, I couldn't add plugin, no button for this adding new plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in multisite options.

For fixing it I just removed multisiting in wp-config, these lines:

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
```

define( 'MULTISITE', true);

True changes to false:

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', false );
```

define( 'MULTISITE', false );